# How to break a for-loop with a nested setTimeout() function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

**The Situation**

I have a function which is called on button click and which should draw an animated chart, updating the chart every 2 seconds. When the user clicks that button again, while the animation is still running, the animation should stop.

**My current solution**

Right now I have the following script which stops the animation visually, but the underlying for-loop continues until the end in the background:

```
var animRun = false;
$("#animateButton").on("click", function() {
    if (animRun === false) {
        redraw(data.slice(0,30))
        //some CSS...

    } else {
        //Some CSS...
        animRun = false;
    }
});

function redraw(data) {
    animRun = true;

    for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){

        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(animRun === true) {
                    //draw the chart
                    return draw(data[i])
                }
            },2000*(i))

            if (i === data.length -1) {
                //reset animRun
                if(animRun === true) {
                     //Some CSS things
                     //...
                     animRun = false;
                 }
            }
        })(i);
    }


}
```

**Question**

What would be the correct way of stopping the for-loop when the user clicks the button again while the animation is still executing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Comment: So it is not possible? What could be a workaround?

Comment: Almost: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation

Comment: The animation I use is made with the d3.js library... In my case I actually stop the animation because the variable `animRun` is set to `false` on the second click, thus the `draw()` function is not executed

Comment: In all seriousness, with some significant rewrite, you should employ [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `clearTimeout`. Store your draw timeout to an array, and stop it when you done

```
var animRun = false;
var drawArr = [];
$("#animateButton").on("click", function() {
    if (animRun === false) {
        redraw(data.slice(0,30))
        //some CSS...

    } else {
        //Some CSS...
        animRun = false;

        drawArr.forEach(d=>clearTimeout(d));
    }
});

function redraw(data) {
    animRun = true;

    for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){

        (function(i){
            drawArr[i] = setTimeout(function(){
                if(animRun === true) {
                    //draw the chart
                    return draw(data[i])
                }
            },2000*(i))

            if (i === data.length -1) {
                //reset animRun
                if(animRun === true) {
                     //Some CSS things
                     //...
                     animRun = false;
                 }
            }
        })(i);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm! I just don't get why it should be a list. because the list is filled after each iteration, isn't it? So if the user stops the animation after the first run of `draw()` there is only one element in `drawArr`. How is it that it clears all following iterations as well?

Comment: Just reinit that array when you click start again `drawArr = []`